# Unable to send messages with websocket in play 2.3.x

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, akka, actor

I am trying to implement websocket using play 2.3.x. I want server to be able to send message to one client or all the client. 
Here is my controller code:

```
object Client extends Controller {
  def socket(guid: String) = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[String, String] { request =>
    out => ClientWebSocketActor.props(guid, out)
  }
```

And below is my Actor code:

```
object ClientWebSocketActor {
  def props(uuid: String, out: ActorRef) = Props(new ClientWebSocketActor(uuid, out))

}

class ClientWebSocketActor(uuid: String, out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  val (enumerator, channel) = Concurrent.broadcast[String]
  var clients = Map[String, (Enumerator[String], Channel[String])]()
  import ClientWebSocketActor._

  def receive = {
    case msg: String =>
      println(msg)
      val (enumerator, channel1) = Concurrent.broadcast[String]
      clients += ((uuid, (enumerator, channel1)))
      println(clients)
      channel1 push "Message is " + msg
  }
}
```

Issue I am facing:

- channel1 push doesn't reply to the client that sent the message
- In clients map all the clients are not added
- channel push msg doesn't work to send message to all clients

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're creating an `Actor` per client, so **1)** To reply to the client that sent the message, you should send the message to the `out` `ActorRef`. **2)** Each client `Actor` shouldn't be keeping a reference to all other clients, there should be a single source of truth. **3)** Fails because of **2**, but also each `Actor` has their own `(enumerator, channel)`, but that is not in any way hooked up to other client `Actor`s.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.This clarifies a lot of things. So what is the best way to send a message to all clients connected to the server and how can i send messages to a group of clients. I am newbie in Scala and just can't wrap my head around this. Really appreciate your help.